# Change coordinate System Space

Tags: math, matrix

I have a question that might be obvious, but I have problems resolving it...

I have 2 coordinate systems . Let's say
Oxyz with x(1,0,0), y(0,1,0), and z(0,0,1) and O(0,0,0). And Px'y'z' with P and x' y' z' known.

My goal here is to create the rotation Matrix that permit me to pass from Oxyz to Px'y'z'.

What I did is : 
calculate Xangle between vector Ox and Px' (by using the formula : 
`Theta = cos( Ox . Px' / ||Ox|| * ||Px'|| ) )`. And create the XMatrix using theta :

```
|1 0          0           |
|0 cos(Theta) -sin(Theta) |
|0 sin(Theta) cos(Theta)  |
```

I do Exactly the same for Yangle and Zangle, then creates the 2 corresponding Matrix. 
After all of this, I create MFinal = XMatrix * YMatrix * ZMatrix.

Is it right?  Can it works in any world?

Thanks for all! :)

Best regards

Comment: You say you want a rotation. Are you sure that `x', y', z'` is an orthonormal basis of R^3?

Comment: Yes, it is. I create them using cross product or so. 
I'm sure that (x', y', z') and (x,y,z) are orthonormals basis of R^3 :)

Comment: In fact, I just need the rotation matrix from a change of Basis... But I don't understand why my method doesn't work /: I made some modification : to put x' on the plane xOy, i have to rotate Ox' around Z, and so on. But still not working. :/

Comment: As written, this is more of a mathematics question than a programming question. Can you edit this question to make it more about programming, such as showing (some of) your code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Sorry, I was on a trip for a while. you are true, I will get this post closed this post since it's more mathematics than programming. It's actually being used in a program, but the problem here is mathematical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method does not work because you do not measure the angle in the plane orthogonal to the axes. The component of the difference vectors that is parallel to the rotation axis will not change by rotation.

Anyway, there is a much simpler method. Assume that the rotation matrix is `R`. Then you want the original x-axis be mapped to the new x-axis:

```
x' = R x = R (1, 0, 0)^T
```

Since the base coordinate system is the canonical system, the last expression evaluates to the first column of `R` and you get:

```
x' = R[0]
```

And this is pretty easy to solve.

So all you need to do is put the local axes as column vectors into `R`. If you want to include a translation, just do the same with the local origin and the fourth column.